# How to implement req/res interceptors

Tags: javascript, node.js, feathersjs

I try to implement Request/Response interceptors using feathers-client.

The purpose is to add global meta-data to the request and strip the response body. Additional I want to use the response interceptor to implement a global error handler.

I looked at the hooks but it seems the `after*` Hooks wont be executed if any error happens.

```
feathersclient()
  ...
  .configure(function() {
      const app = this;
      app.mixins.push(function(service) {
        service.before(function(hook) {
          console.log('SENT', service.path, hook);
          return hook;
        });
        service.after(function(hook) {
          // Never fired if req produces an error
          console.log('RECEIVE', service.path, hook);
          return hook;
        });
      });
  })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct, unfortunately there is not a great way to hook into errors that happen. v1.6.0 of feathers-hooks will support `onError` handlers however. Until then you could create a service mixin with your own error handler like this:

```
feathersclient()
  ...
  .configure(function() {
    const app = this;
    app.mixins.push(function(service) {
      const mixin = {};

      app.methods.forEach(method => {
        if(typeof service[method] === 'function') {
          mixin[method] = function(... args) {
            return this._super(... args).catch(error => {
              // do some error handling here
              throw error;
            });
          }
        }
      });

      service.mixin(mixin);
    });
  })
```

Comment: Release post for error hooks: https://blog.feathersjs.com/feathers-application-and-error-hooks-7a5982e70024

Answer (score 0):

Sadly I could it only solve by monky-patching the send-method:

```
    app.mixins.push(function(service) {
      // monky patch send() to fetch errors
      const oldSend = service.send;
      service.send = function(...args) {
        return oldSend.apply(service, args)
          .catch(e => {
            console.log('ERR', e);
            throw e; // re-throw error
          });
      };
    });
```